# What is the package name of google hangouts meet?

Tags: android, google-hangouts

"com.google.android.talk" is not worked for me. What is the actual package name of current hangouts meet app. I want to send the users to this app from my app.

Comment: See this for reference https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me. I wanted to go to  a conference which is created for my app. Getting the meeting ID from the conference, I have successfully entered to Google Meet app. So, the package name is not needed.

```
   //String meetingId = event.getHangoutLink();

    Uri conference = Uri.parse(meetingId);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, conference);

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = 
         packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mapIntent, 0);

    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

    if (isIntentSafe)
    {
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
```